# Azure DevOps for Azure PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql-11, postgresql-12, azure-postgresql

I did some research and found that Azure DevOps does have any outofthebox implementations to support CI CD for Azure PostgreSQL.

Does anyone , have any idea , How can we configure Azure DevOps for PaaS offering of Azure PostgreSQL Database

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today , there is no out-of-the-box Azure DevOps template to deploy for the PaaS version of Azure Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand OP's question correctly, and it's been 9 months since OP posted the question. But this appears to be the right answer.

At least one Microsoft-hosted agent on Azure Devops has PostgreSQL built in, just not enabled by default. Enabling and using it is simple.

The "Microsoft-hosted agents" page, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml, has a table listing the available agents. You can click on the link in the rightmost column to see a list of included software. The link for the agent *vs2017-win2016* points to [a list of all the software pre-installed on the Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Datacenter](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2016-Readme.md). Scrolling down the page, or searching for "postgres", reveals the pertinent information for PostgreSQL.

This example Azure Pipelines job can be used to start PostgreSQL.

```
- job: foo-postgresql-bar
  pool:
    vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'
  steps:
    - powershell: |
        echo 'PGBIN is ' $env:PGBIN
        echo 'PGDATA is ' $env:PGDATA
        echo 'PGROOT is ' $env:PGROOT
        echo 'Contents of PGBIN'
        ls $env:PGBIN
        Set-Service postgresql-x64-13 -StartupType manual
        Start-Service postgresql-x64-13
        Get-CimInstance win32_service | Where-Object Name -eq "postgresql-x64-13"
      displayName: 'Setup PostgreSQL'
```

Only the `Set-Service` and `Start-Service` commands are required; the rest of the PowerShell script is optional.

The `echo` and `ls` commands simply verify the information from the table. The `Set-Service` command enables the service, the `Start-Service` command starts the service, and the `Get-CimInstance` command verifies that it's running.

In a production environment, you may read the return code after `Start-Service`, instead of using the `Get-CimInstance` command, in order to verify that the service is running.